# Jquery Quicksearch plugin issue with dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quicksearch is really cool... but it has a usability issue that makes it behave weird. A lot of users presses enter after inserting a string so the page is reloaded with no parameters and the queries are destroyed.

look at that:
http://www.parksmania.it/parco_list.php?rid=1

Adding

```
$('form#filtroRapido').submit(function () { return false; });
```

doesn't work!
Has someone already solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with live ?

```
$('form#filtroRapido').live('submit', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this yet?

```
$('form#filtroRapido').submit(function (eve) {
    eve.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```